What's recursive relation, how's it different from recurring relation, how's induction definition rule applied in recursive relation
Basic content and definitions
Induction definition rule and it's stepwise proofs
Application of Fibonacci definition rule
Possible mathematical expression and word problems

Hey just want to let you know before your question inevitably gets closed that you need to put waaaay more effort into your questions here than this to receive answers.
